# IObservable.Subscribe causing System.Delegate.CreateDelegate to throw an ArgumentException

Tags: .net, f#, sdl, system.reactive

I was hoping to hook cs-sdl up to Rx. I've gotten it to work in C#, but in F# something rather strange starts to happen. I'd like to stick to F# so that I can save on some programming time and pass SDL events as arguments to neatly wrap them in IObservables. Here is how I attempted to do so:

```
let fromEvent (e: IEvent<'H,'T>) = Observable.FromEventPattern<'H,'T>((fun h -> e.AddHandler(h)),(fun h -> e.RemoveHandler(h)))
```

All well and good so far. Now to pass it one of the SDL events and get an IObservable...

```
let MouseMotion = fromEvent(Events.MouseMotion)
```

And so on and so on goes this set of modules. All the inferred types are correct. MouseMotion is of type `IObservable<MouseMotionEventArgs>`

Now here is where I actually use this library in another project I made for testing it:

```
let observer : IObserver<MouseMotionEventArgs> = Observer.Create(Action<MouseMotionEventArgs>(fun x -> System.Console.WriteLine(x.X.ToString())))
ignore <| SdlDotNet.Reactive.CoreInput.MouseMotion.Subscribe(Observer.AsObserver(observer))
```

Here is what happens when I run it:

```
  System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  Message="Type must derive from Delegate.\r\nParameter name: type"
  Source="mscorlib"
  ParamName="type"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate(Type type, Object firstArgument, MethodInfo method, Boolean throwOnBindFailure)
       at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate(Type type, Object firstArgument, MethodInfo method)
       at System.Reactive.Linq.Observable.<>c__DisplayClass19d`2.<FromEvent>b__19b(IObserver`1 observer)
       at System.Reactive.AnonymousObservable`1.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Subscribe>b__0()
       at System.Reactive.Concurrency.Scheduler.Invoke(IScheduler scheduler, Action action)
       at System.Reactive.Concurrency.ScheduledItem`2.InvokeCore()
       at System.Reactive.Concurrency.ScheduledItem`1.Invoke()
       at System.Reactive.Concurrency.CurrentThreadScheduler.Trampoline.Run()
       at System.Reactive.Concurrency.CurrentThreadScheduler.Schedule[TState](TState state, TimeSpan dueTime, Func`3 action)
       at System.Reactive.Concurrency.CurrentThreadScheduler.Schedule[TState](TState state, Func`3 action)
       at System.Reactive.Concurrency.Scheduler.Schedule(IScheduler scheduler, Action action)
       at System.Reactive.AnonymousObservable`1.Subscribe(IObserver`1 observer)
       at <StartupCode$SdlDemo>.$Tutorial.main@() in C:\Users\Barend Venter\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SdlDemo\SdlDemo\Tutorial.fs:line 77
  InnerException:
```

I am completely stumped. Why is this happening? Is there some eta-expansion I need to do somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some fiddling, I was able to turn the runtime exception into a handy type error. It seems that changing the type of observer from `IObserver<MouseMotionEventArgs>` to `IObserver<EventPattern<MouseMotionEventArgs>>` does the trick here:

```
let observer = Observer.Create(fun (x : EventPattern<MouseMotionEventArgs>) -> System.Console.WriteLine(x.EventArgs.X.ToString()))
ignore <| SdlDotNet.Reactive.CoreInput.MouseMotion.Subscribe((observer))
```

It is perhaps unfortunate that a solution that eluded me for days would come to me so soon after posting here. Hopefully it'll prove useful for someone.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating your own wrapper functions to adapt F# to Rx, why not just use the functions in the standard F# [`Control.Observable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370313.aspx) module?

Comment: Because Control.Observable lacks a "concat". This is a very useful thing to have, because that way one IObservable can be used to switch between other IObservables of the same type, and it forms a monad, which is nice for making a workflow builder. There might be a way to implement it but it isn't obvious to me how.

Comment: `Observable.merge<'T>` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353488.aspx) performs the "concat" you need to create your workflow builder.

Comment: I thought for a minute I would be able to use merge and was trying to find a way to get it the right type. However, it turns out that merge is a disjunction operation, so even if I were to derive an `IObservable<IObservable<'T>> -> IObservable<'T>`, instead of switching the old event sources out, it'd keep sending signals from them along with ones from the new sources pushed.

Answer (score 1):

This may not solve the rest of your problem, but did you notice that [IEvent inherits from IObservable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340439.aspx)? Your `fromEvent` function could be implemented as a simple cast...

```
let fromEvent (e: IEvent<'H,'T>) = e :> IObservable<'T>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is just an issue of confusing naming. The IObservable being cast to is F#'s own IObservable, not the Rx IObservable which came later. Hopefully, if Rx is rolled into .NET, the F# IObservable will be deprecated or just switched out.

Comment: Then why is it defined in the System namespace, in [mscorlib.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377(v=vs.100).aspx)?

Comment: With .NET Framework 4.0 and VS 2010, F# got blessed as one of the .NET languages distributed with Visual Studio. I'm using .NET 3.5 for this project, and F#'s IObservable does not live in mscorlib for me (it instead lives in Fsharp.Core, however IObservable is still defined in the System namespace as System.IObservable, which is unfortunately the exact same name the IObservable imported with System.Reactive has).